# Entity Framework : How to groupjoin? (Query users within location with additional requirements)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Scenario:

A user can assign himself multiple categories (ex. "fishing", "stackoverflowfan", etc..) 
 
User A wants to befriend(connection) a similar user B. 
 
There are plenty of similar user B's, so user A wants to narrow it down based on location & activity of user B. 
Also user A obviously doesn't want someone he or she already befriended or blocked.

How would I implement this in Entity Framework (Core)?
 
I've got it to work for just finding based on location and activity date and I also think filtering on connections(befriending) and blocked users, but filtering it on those **categories** got me scratching my head a bit.

The result that I picture in my head:
 
If there would be x-amount of users in the system it should get:
 
1) closest users in x-radius (ex. 10 km/miles)
 
2) based on those closest users, order it based on similar categories
 
3) cool, we have users with similar categories, now let's see who of those users was recently online, but categories are more important and maybe also a order by closest location? or is that too much?

**UserId** |              **Location**     | **ActivityDate** | **Categories** 
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
     21    | point( lon lat) within radius | 2017-26-01       | {1,2,12,3,5} (5 common categories) 
     12    | point( lon lat) within radius | 2017-26-06       | {1,2,12} (3 common categories) 
     13    | point( lon lat) within radius | 2017-26-07       | {1,2} (2 common categories) 
     44    | point( lon lat) within radius | 2017-26-07       | {} (0 common categories) 
     25    | point( lon lat) within radius | 2017-26-06       | {} (0 common categories) 
     33    | point( lon lat) within radius | 2017-26-05       | {} (0 common categories)

Extra: While we are on a streak, I want activitydate (so last login) not just ordered but for example maximum 2 weeks old, because no use in befriending a user who hasn't been online in decades, no matter how many similar categories they have.

Here is a simple example of the models:

User Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; } 
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    //User can have multiple connections
    public ICollection<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
    //User can have multiple categories
    public ICollection<UserCategory> UserCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Category Model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Category can have multiple users
    public ICollection<UserCategory> UserCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Intersection Table UserCategory (ManyToMany - User with Categories):

```
public class UserCategory
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Intersection Table Connection (ManyToMany - User with User):

```
public class Connection
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int UserConnectionId { get; set; }
    public User UserConnection { get; set; }

    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
return await myDBContext.User.AsNoTracking().FromSql(
        @"DECLARE @from geography = geography::STPointFromText([Location])', 4326);
            DECLARE @to geography = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST({0} AS VARCHAR(20)) +' ' + CAST({1} AS VARCHAR(20)) +')', 4326);
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.User
        WHERE @from.STDistance(@to) <= @p0",
        requestor.Location.Longitude,
        requestor.Location.Latitude,
        requestor.Appsetting.Radius)
        .Where(x => !x.Connections.Any(y => y.UserId == requestor.Id))
        .GroupJoin(/*do I use groupjoin?...*/).OrderBy(/*...*/).ThenBy(x => x.ActivityDate) //<=========
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(take)
        .ToListAsync();
```

P.S: I'm working in Entity Framework Core (so DBGeography is out of the question)

Any push in the right direction is very much appriciated!

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "order it based on similar categories"? What *exactly* do you want to order by?

Comment: @GertArnold : Well, I'm trying to get users within a specific radius. But the users should be prioritized ( or ordered by ) firstly on the total of common categories, then most active then range

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `GroupJoin` because you can use the existing navigation properties to let EF generate the required joins in SQL. The gist of this query is that a user's categories is intersected with another user's categories:

```
var users = myDBContext.User
                       .AsNoTracking().FromSql(...)
                       .Where(x => !x.Connections.Any(y => y.UserId == requestor.Id));
var result = (from u1 in users
             from u2 in u1.Connections.Select(c => c.UserConnection)
             let commonCategories = u1.UserCategory.Select(uc1 => uc1.CategoryId)
                 .Intersect(u2.UserCategory.Select(uc2 => uc2.CategoryId))
             orderby commonCategories.Count(), u1.ActivityDate
             select new
             {
                 u2.Id,
                 u2.Location,
                 u2.ActivityDate,
                 CommonCategories = commonCategories.Select(cc => cc.Id)
             })
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(x => new
             {
                 x.Id,
                 x.Location,
                 x.ActivityDate,
                 Categories = string.Join(",", x.CommonCategories)
             });
```

The `AsEnumerable()` statement is put in-between to continue the query execution as LINQ-to-objects, because LINQ-to-entities doesn't support `string.Join`.

Note: I'm not sure if you'd want the first user's Id in there too. This query produces a list of connected users per user in `users`, so without the first user's Id you can't tell to which user each row belongs. It's not necessary if you execute this query for one user.